# Как перезапускать телеграмм бота на pythonanywhere каждые несколько часов?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, subprocess, pythonanywhere

Есть готовый телеграмм бот, когда запустил его на pythonanywhere, то заметил, что через некоторое время он перестает работать.

Также пробовал `subprocess.call(['python','bot.py'])`, чтобы он перезапускал сам себя каждые 6 часов. К сожалению из-за этого возникают многие другие ошибки (бот не "слушает" сообщение или слушает, но не перезапускается). Есть ли какой-то способ, чтобы перезапустить консоль в файле?

```
from time import time, sleep
import subprocess
time_now = time()
while True:
    print(time() - time_now)
    sleep(1)
    if time() - time_now > 3600*6:
        print(time() - time_now)
        subprocess.call(['python','bot.py'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых посоветую Вам библиотеку [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), если вам нужно периодически что-то делать в питоне (ваш код можно сильно упростить с ней), по ней есть много видеоуроков.

В pythonanywhere есть такая вещь, как Tasks:
`https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/<your_username>/tasks_tab/`, там можно устанавливать ежедневные задачи, в вашем случае перезапуска бота.

*Ну вроде всё, что я хотел сказать)*